# Previous set variables values are becoming null

Tags: android

I am having class called global which extends Application, to maintain the values which had got in the first activity to next activity i am using this class by using the getter and setter functions. whenever i want to get or set any values from the current activity i create a static object of the global class. App will work properly for the first time launch and after the also till half an hour. if me want to resume the application after half an hour all the variables decalred in the global class becoming null and the variables of the resuming activity is also becoming null.

i am sure there is a some problem in my code. i request you to any one to help me to get rid of this bug.

please see my code here
package com.globalnest;

import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalClass extends Application {
    public int displayTab = 0;

```
public int getDisplayTab() {
    return displayTab;
}

public void setDisplayTab(int displayTab) {
    this.displayTab = displayTab;
}

public boolean isLeaddetails;

public boolean isLeaddetails() {
    return isLeaddetails;
}

public void setLeaddetails(boolean isLeaddetails) {
    this.isLeaddetails = isLeaddetails;
}

public static boolean startedApp;

public boolean isStartedApp() {
    return startedApp;
}

public void setStartedApp(boolean startedApp1) {
    startedApp = startedApp1;
}

public String accessToken;
public String boothId;
public String eventBrite;
public String scanedQR;
public String fname;
public String lname;
public String cname;
public String Id;
public String emailId;
public String ph;
public String note;
public String title;
public String date;
public String cat;
public String booth_fname;


public void setMyBoothFirstName(String booth_fname) {
    this.booth_fname = booth_fname;
}

public String getMyBoothFirstName() {
    return booth_fname;
}

public void setMyCategory(String cat) {
    this.cat = cat;
}

public String getMyCategory() {
    return cat;
}

public void setMyDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getMyDate() {

    return date;
}

public void setMyTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getMyTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setMyNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}

public String getMyNote() {
    return note;
}

public void setMyPh(String ph) {
    this.ph = ph;
}

public String getMyPh() {
    return ph;
}

public void setMyEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

public String getMyEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public void setMyScanedId(String Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}

public String getMyScanedId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setMyfname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getMyfname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setMylname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getMylname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setMycname(String cname) {
    this.cname = cname;
}

public String getMycname() {
    return cname;
}

public void setMyAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

public String getMyAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

public void setMyBoothId(String boothId) {
    this.boothId = boothId;
}

public String getMyBoothId() {
    return boothId;
}

public void setMyEventBrite(String eventBrite) {
    this.eventBrite = eventBrite;
}

public String getMyEvetBrite() {
    return eventBrite;
}

public void setMyScanedQR(String scanedQR) {
    this.scanedQR = scanedQR;
}

public String getMyScanedQR() {
    return scanedQR;
}
```

}

public class AutoSearchText extends ListActivity {

```
static String rFirstName = null, rLastName = null, rCompanyName = null,
        string_qrcode;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "qr";
private ListView listView;
static AutoCompleteTextView et;
String resp;
int a;
private MyArrayAdapter adapter;
static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static List<String> data, fname;
private static List<String> newdata, newdata1, qrcode, sorted_qrcode;
private static List<String> data1, sorted_visits, company;
static GlobalClass global;
Cursor cur = null;
String s = null;
String result = null;
String[] array1, array2;
String[] array, arry_qrcode;
static EditText textView;
static String clickQR = null;
TextView total;
Runnable r;
Bundle inBundle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    inBundle = savedInstanceState;
    setContentView(R.layout.list_main);




    r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            data = new LinkedList<String>();
            fname = new LinkedList<String>();
            sorted_visits = new LinkedList<String>();
            data1 = new LinkedList<String>();
            company = new LinkedList<String>();
            newdata = new LinkedList<String>();
            newdata1 = new LinkedList<String>();
            qrcode = new LinkedList<String>();
            sorted_qrcode = new LinkedList<String>();
            global = (GlobalClass) getApplication();
            System.out.println("Start posting");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(),
                            "Loading...", "Leads");
                }
            });

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            get_leads();
            total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_lead);
            // Cursor cur = null;

            // data.add(s);
            System.out.println("data" + data);

            if (data != null && result != null) {
                // tv.setText(data.size()+" Leads");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(data.size() + " Leads");
                    }
                });

                // tv.setText(a+" Leads");

                array = new String[data.size()];
                array1 = new String[data1.size()];
                array2 = new String[company.size()];
                arry_qrcode = new String[qrcode.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                    array[i] = data.get(i);
                    array1[i] = data1.get(i);
                    array2[i] = company.get(i);
                    arry_qrcode[i] = qrcode.get(i);
                }
                String[] a = { "1", "2" };
                adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(AutoSearchText.this, array,
                        array1, array2, arry_qrcode);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

            }

            listView = getListView();
            listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
                    clickQR = holder.getQrcode();
                    global.setMyScanedQR(clickQR);
                    if (isOnline()) {
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(),
                                "Verifying ..", "Please Wait..");

                        try {
                            InputMethodManager imethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext()
                                    .getSystemService(
                                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                                    textView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        new GetDataTask().execute();
                    } else {
                        alert("Warning",
                                "Please check your Data Connection");
                    }
                    // Toast.makeText(AutoSearchText.this,
                    // holder.getQrcode(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

        }
    };

    textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search);

    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count){
            int textlength=0;
            if(s!=null){
             textlength = s.length();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EDit text  is null", 600000).show();
                return;

            }

           newdata.clear();
           newdata1.clear();

           sorted_visits.clear();
           sorted_qrcode.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= array[i].length()) {
                    if (array[i].subSequence(0, array[i].length())
                            .toString().toUpperCase()
                            .indexOf(s.toString().toUpperCase()) != -1) {
                        newdata.add(array[i]);
                        newdata1.add(array2[i]);
                        sorted_visits.add(array1[i]);
                        sorted_qrcode.add(arry_qrcode[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (newdata.size() > 0) {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String[] a = { "1", "2" };
                adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getParent(),
                        (String[]) newdata.toArray(new String[0]),
                        (String[]) sorted_visits.toArray(new String[0]),
                        (String[]) newdata1.toArray(new String[0]),
                        (String[]) sorted_qrcode.toArray(new String[0]));
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                listView = getListView();
            } else {

                listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            /*
             * if (newdata != null&&result!=null) { array = new
             * String[newdata.size()]; array1= new String[newdata.size()];
             * for (int i = 0; i < newdata.size(); i++) { array[i] =
             * newdata.get(i); array1[i]=newdata.get(i); } String[]
             * a={"1","2"}; adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getParent(),
             * array,array1); setListAdapter(adapter); } listView =
             * getListView(); listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
             * listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);}
             */}
    });

}

/*******************************************************************
 * 
 * @Desc : This method to diplsy alert when connection not available and
 *       control navigate to scan
 * @param : String
 * @return : none
 * 
 *         ********************************************************
 */

private void alert(String title, String error) {

    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent()).create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(error);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            try {

                global.setDisplayTab(0);
                Intent i = new Intent(getParent(), AdminTabHost.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();

}

private void get_leads() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        String url = "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/getLead?Id="
                + global.getMyBoothId();

        // URLEncoder.encode(textView.getText().toString(),"UTF-8"));
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        System.out.println("url" + url);
        // https://na7.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/GlobalNestEM/Verify_Lead?Id"+global.getMyBoothId()+"&Barcode=100000051
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // set up time out connection 30s
        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        String token = "00DA0000000L49t!AQ8AQFxfw19eJBNw_NNxyesR.PTOiFMpZP4SrXkEpSZ3tl_Hr4btzhggN_KVwT5x3cS1o0ohcVSeIBYC1aLkhWMitSA05JUt";
        httpGet.addHeader("Authorization",
                "OAuth " + global.getMyAccessToken());
        // System.out.println("post acessToken"+global.getMyAccessToken());
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        System.out.println("res for getLead" + result);
        JSONArray ja;
        String s = null;
        // progressDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            ja = new JSONArray(result);
            // JSONObject j=new JSONObject(ja);
            ja.length();
            a = ja.length();
            System.out.println("xxxx" + ja.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                String visits = null;
                String date_global = null, temp = null;
                try {
                    visits = ja
                            .getJSONObject(i)
                            .get("Attendee_NextFollowUpDate__c")
                            .toString();

                    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
                    temp = df2.format(df1.parse(visits));
                    date_global = temp.replace('-', '/').toString();

                    // s=visits.replace('-','/').toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                rLastName = ja.getJSONObject(i)
                        .get("Attendee_LastName__c")
                        .toString();
                rCompanyName = ja.getJSONObject(i)
                        .get("Attendee_Company__c")
                        .toString();
                rFirstName = ja.getJSONObject(i)
                        .get("Attendee_FirstName__c")
                        .toString();

                System.out.println("rFirstName" + rFirstName + ja.length());
                try {
                    string_qrcode = ja.getJSONObject(i)
                            .get("Attendee_BarCode1__c")
                            .toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                fname.add(rFirstName);
                data.add(rFirstName + " " + rLastName);

                // data.add(rFirstName + "\n" + rLastName);
                // newdata.add(rFirstName+"\n"+rLastName);
                data1.add(date_global);
                company.add(rCompanyName);
                qrcode.add(string_qrcode);
            }
            // System.out.println(""+ja.getJSONObject(0).get("Attendee_LastName__c"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Result lead details" + result);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                alert("Warning", "Please check your Data Connection");

            }
        });
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                alert("Warning", "Please check your Data Connection");

            }
        });
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        alert("Warning", "Please check your Data Connection");
    }
}

private Boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
        return true;

    return false;
}

private void alertDialog(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder d1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
    d1.setMessage(string);
    d1.setTitle("Search Result");
    d1.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
    d1.setCancelable(true);
    d1.create().show();
}

public static String postPost(String s) throws NoNetWorkException {
    System.out.println("Start posting");
    global.setMyfname(null);
    global.setMyEmailId(null);
    global.setMyNote(null);
    global.setMylname(null);
    global.setMyDate(null);
    global.setMycname(null);
    global.setMyPh(null);
    global.setMyTitle(null);
    String result = null;

    try {
        String url = "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Verify_Lead?Id="
                + global.getMyBoothId()
                + "&Barcode="
                + clickQR
                + "&EventBrite=" + global.getMyEvetBrite() + "";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        System.out.println("url" + url);
        // https://na7.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/GlobalNestEM/Verify_Lead?Id"+global.getMyBoothId()+"&Barcode=100000051
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // set up time out connection 30s
   /*     int timeoutConnection = 30000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 30000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);*/
        httpGet.addHeader("Authorization",
                "OAuth " + global.getMyAccessToken());
        // System.out.println("post acessToken"+global.getMyAccessToken());
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Verify result" + result);
        // return result;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new NoNetWorkException();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new NoNetWorkException();
    }

    return result;
}

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (isOnline()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(0);
                resp = postPost("");
                System.out.println(" post responceforVerify= " + resp);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoNetWorkException e) {
                Log.d("No NetWork", "No NetWork");
                resp = "no network";
                return resp;

            }

        }
        return resp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (resp.equalsIgnoreCase("no network")) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    alert("Warning", "Please check your Data Connection");

                }
            });

        } else if (result != null) {
            if (!result.contains("Error__c")) {

                try {
                    // response manipulation
                    String currentDateTimeString = getdate();
                    JSONObject ja = new JSONObject(result);
                    global.setMyfname(ja.get(
                            "Attendee_FirstName__c")
                            .toString());
                    try {

                        try {
                            global.setMyCategory(ja
                                    .get("Attendee_LeadCategory__c")
                                    .toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            global.setMyEmailId(ja.get(
                                    "Attendee_EmailId__c")
                                    .toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            global.setMyNote(ja
                                    .get("Attendee_GatheredComments__c")
                                    .toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            global.setMyTitle(ja
                                    .get("Attendee_Designation__c")
                                    .toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            String v, d_g, t;
                            v = ja.get(
                                    "Attendee_NextFollowUpDate__c")
                                    .toString();

                            DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                    "yyyy-MM-dd");
                            DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                    "MM-dd-yyyy");
                            t = df2.format(df1.parse(v));
                            d_g = t.replace('-', '/').toString();
                            global.setMyDate(d_g);

                            // global.setMyDate(ja.get("Attendee_NextFollowUpDate__c").toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            global.setMyPh(ja
                                    .get("Attendee_PhoneNumber__c")
                                    .toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ja.get("Attendee_Company__c");
                        // global.setMyScanedId(ja.get("Id").toString());
                        global.setMycname(ja.get(
                                "Attendee_Company__c")
                                .toString());
                        global.setMylname(ja.get(
                                "Attendee_LastName__c")
                                .toString());
                        System.out.println("verify values" + resp);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    global.setDisplayTab(1);
                    global.setLeaddetails(true);
                    Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), LeadDetails.class);
                    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
                    parentActivity.startChildActivity("Verify", edit);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    alertDialog("Invalid QR Code");

                }

            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject ja = new JSONObject(result);
                    alertDialog(ja.get("Error__c").toString());
                    // startChildActivity("EditActivity", new
                    // Intent(this,LeadDetails.class));
                    /*
                     * Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(),
                     * LeadDetails.class); TabGroupActivity parentActivity =
                     * (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
                     * parentActivity.startChildActivity("LeadDetails",
                     * edit);
                     */
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(ne
```

Comment: god knows, that the entire source file was not needed.. please reduce your code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the problem is necessarily in your code, that is happening when Android doesn't have enough memory for the foreground app and it releases from memory objects from the background applications.. I think this is in your case too.. 
I think the only thing to do is to check for null the objects you use and init them again with some default values.. 
see here: the [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#Activity%20Lifecycle) for more info..

Answer (score 0):

Problem is surely in your lifecycle management.  Values of static variables survive as long as JVM ( Davlik in this case)  is running.  But OS can kill it whenever it likes the idea - so most probably your variables are null after complete restart.

Seeing from your source code,  you are subclassing application class. If this is the case,you shall also use it in manifest.

I also see issue in your runnable -   you are doing findViewById() inside run() method -
this is suboptimal ( you shall do this in onCreateMethod()  of your activity )

Your global storage class will not survive application restart - all values will be lost.

If you like to vave state persistence, you shall store values somewhere else (shared preferences  are good choice for this).  To make your life easier, you can grab small library I wrote:

[here](https://github.com/ko5tik/andject)

I will make your life easier marshalling and unmarshaling object fields into preferences objects.

Comment: even though if me does not run single application also it will crashing. i checked with other application in that it is not happening like this

Answer (score 0):

Ok here you go,

you can set the value in `Application` class using `getApplicationContext()`

```
((GlobalClass)getApplicationContext()).setLastName("Poptani");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried but there is no result. it still persist null.